# Laravel equivalent query builder

Tags: php, laravel

How to convert below query into Laravel equivalent query builder

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE '03-05-2017 09:30' BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date` AND `who_should`='VV000'
```

I tried using **whereBetween** but not working as expected.

Comment: Generally `column_name BETWEEN '03-05-2017 09:30' AND '10-05-2017 09:30'` is the format I am unable to understand the Logic where you are checking the constant value...

Comment: There is start_date & end_date columns

Comment: You can use `where > and < `or you can add raw where clause in `whereRaw` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$given_time = "03-05-2017 09:30";    
\DB::table('table_name')
        ->whereRaw(" '$given_time' Between start_date  and end_date ")
        ->where("who_should", "=", "VV000")
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new Carbon\Carbon('03-05-2017 09:30'); 
        $date_string=$date->toDateTimeString();

        $data_set = DB::table('table_name')
        ->select(DB::raw('*'))
        ->where('start_date', '<', $date_string )
        ->where('end_date', '>', $date_string )     
        ->where('who_should','=','VV000')
        ->get();
```

Try above code

Comment: I dont know why its showing error syntax error, unexpected '$data_set' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: missed semicolon $date_string=$date->toDateTimeString();

Comment: Still getting this syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Its same, no difference

Comment: I have changed date_string to $date_string previously,
now there should not contain an error,
You may also need to call use Carbon; before defining your controller class

Comment: my bad, some other issue. but not returning same results as normal query

Comment: you may want to change <,> logic?

Comment: also I think there are some issues in your raw sql query, 
Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143075/discussion-between-ashanrupasinghe-and-zack).